# Need to find a description for the CSC7102C

Tags: integrated-circuit

I was trying to search for the `CSC7102C` on google and couldn't find any description for it.

What is the function of this IC?

Comment: Is there any photo of the IC? What you wrote may not be the part name.

Comment: Photo of the IC please clearly showing the markings on the IC please ...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Polish electronics forums post,](https://www.elektroda.pl/rtvforum/topic3816656.html) the CSC7102C is a 5V, 3W switching regulator for stepping down line voltage to 5V.

The author of that post couldn't find a datasheet for the CSC7102C, but notes that it is very similar to the [iW1810](https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/sites/default/files/iw1810_datasheet_12.5.2018.pdf)

You could compare your circuit to the suggested circuit for the iW1810:

[image]